# Can you use generic forms in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

You should be able to create a generic form:

```
public partial class MyGenericForm<T> :
    Form where T : class
{
    /* form code */
    public List<T> TypedList { get; set; }
}
```

Is valid C#, and compiles.  However the designer won't work and the form will throw a runtime exception if you have any images stating that it cannot find the resource.

I think this is because the windows forms designer assumes that the resources will be stored under the simple type's name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you can! Here's a blog post I made a while ago with the trick:

[Designing Generic Forms](http://www.madprops.org/blog/designing-generic-forms/)

Edit: Looks like you're already doing it this way. This method works fine so I wouldn't consider it too hacky.

Comment: What about if you have 3 forms? I want Form3 : Form2. This includes the generic type parameter + controls in Form2. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have a hack to workaround this, which works but isn't ideal:

Add a new class to the project that inherits the form with its simple name.

```
internal class MyGenericForm:
    MyGenericForm<object> { }
```

This means that although the designer is still wrong the expected simple type (i.e without `<>`) is still found.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in three steps.

1) Replace in Form1.cs File

```
public partial class Form1<TEntity, TContext> : Formbase // where....
```

2) Replace in Form1.Designer.cs

```
 partial class Form1<TEntity, TContext>
```

3) Create new file : Form1.Generic.cs (for opening design)

```
partial class Form1
{
}
```

Comment: 1) that's only 2 steps and b) anything in `*.Designer.cs` is autogenerated by VS and can get overwritten any time

Comment: While running, it does not cause any problems, but the form is problematic during the design phase. For this System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1<TEntity,TContext>));After you edit the row, you must add it again.

Comment: Yes, that's my point - VS might undo your work any time and relying on a manual process to fix that every time is just asking for bugs. At some point you (or someone working with your code) is going to forget and you'll get a run-time bug because it can't find the resource.

Comment: I Added  new file partial class Form1{} its work, designer opened.

Answer (score 0):

If paleolithic code doesn't affraid you

```
    public  static MyForm GetInstance<T>(T arg) where T : MyType
{
    MyForm myForm = new MyForm();

    myForm.InitializeStuffs<T>(arg);
    myForm.StartPosition = myForm.CenterParent;

    return myForm;
}
```

Use it

```
var myFormInstance = MyForm.GetInstance<T>(arg);                                                                      myFormInstance.ShowDialog(this);
```